# To display images from project image folder in mvc application from only a specific ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a internet application that displays images when accessed only from a specific ip address.. i used Request.UserHostAddress to check for ip address in a controller ,i do not get what to do next. i used  in the view to show image but when the address of the image is copied ,the image is being able to copied from any ip addrss. pls help

Comment: pls post some code and a little more explanation

Comment: IP addresses can be faked, especially on an intranet. IP addresses have nothing to do with security.

Comment: BTW,am new to mvc4 and c#. I am trying to learn it on my own. i am instructed to use url to display image and not the path.i used the following in the view <img src="../Pictures/Nurse.jpg" alt="NurseRound" /> and in the controller, the following:    public ActionResult ViewImages()
        {
            if ((Request.UserHostAddress.ToString()) == "ipaddr")
            {           
                return View();
            }
            else
            {

                ViewBag.Message = "You cannot view this page,Access Denied.";
                return View("Denied");
            }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your controller:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```